# Need help shifting fields with populated data over blank fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am hoping that someone may be able to help me with a query that I have been writing.  I am still very new to sql, so if I explain something incorrectly, please let me know.

I have a table with a part number field, and 30 description fields and 30 description value fields.  I am trying to return records in a specific format where there are no records with blank values in front of populated fields.  For example, if I have the following records:

```
Part_Number|Description_1|Description_1_Value|Description_2|Description_2_Value|Description_3|Description_3_Value
123|Color|Red|Material|Wood|Quantity|
456|Color||Material|Steel|Quantity|
789|Color|Black|Material||Quantity|1
```

I want to return the following results:

```
Part_Number|Description 1|Description 2
123|Quantity
456|Color|Quantity
789|Material
```

Here is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT [Part_Number]
,isnull(case when [Description_1_Value] is null then [Description_1] else '' end,'') 'Description 1'
,isnull(case when [Description_2_Value] is null then [Description_2] else '' end,'') 'Description 2'
,isnull(case when [Description_3_Value] is null then [Description_3] else '' end,'') 'Description 3'
FROM [MyTable]
```

The problem that I am having with this query is that it allows blank fields in between fields that are populated.  What is the best way to shift all of the populated fields to the left of all blank fields?  I have 30 columns that may or may not have data in them.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:  I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, Sybase, Oracle?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: check my full example :) hope it helps

Comment: I think... You're after the command [unpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: @xQbert - I am going to read up on this.  I was hoping that I could just make some minor adjustments to my existing query to stay in my comfort zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result set doesn't match the column labels.Unless you want them to be 'Missing Description 1' or something like that.  Example: Row 3, Material is not a Description 1, but you have it in that column.

You want to keep all your values in the same column and concatenate the values with the pipe character if you want them separated.

```
SELECT [Part_Number] 
    ,isnull(case when [Description_1_Value] is null 
                 then [Description_1] + '|' 
                 else '' 
            end
      ,'') 
     + isnull(case when [Description_2_Value] is null 
                     then [Description_2] + '|' 
                     else '' 
                end,'')  
     + isnull(case when [Description_3_Value] is null 
                     then [Description_3] + '|' 
                     else '' 
                end,'') as 'Missing Description'  
FROM [MyTable]
```

You may want to consider redesigning this table. Why can't you have columns: 'Color', 'Quantity', 'Material' ? Or have a separate table called Descritions: with the columns: Part_Number, Description_Label, Description_Value.  If your goal is just to get a list of missing values, You can:

```
Select * from Descriptions Where Description_Value Is Null;
```

Comment: I think your first query will work for me.  I have no control over the design of the table, and there are currently 1600 combinations of descriptions within this table.  One more question...is there a way to eliminate the final "|" if there is not data after it?

Answer (score 2):

Insert the values in a temp table.

Update the rows to solve your blanks problem.

Here it's a full example (I'll insert the values in temp table #table2 and aftwerwords I'll update all rows):

```
create table #test (
id int,
desc1 int null,
desc2 int null,
desc3 int null
)

create table #test2 (
id int,
desc1 varchar(10) null,
desc2 varchar(10) null,
desc3 varchar(10) null
)


insert into #test values (123, 1, 1, NULL), (456, NULL, NULL, 1), (789, 1, NULL, 1)


insert into #test2
select id, 'desc1', null, null from #test
where desc1 is null

insert into #test2
select id, null, 'desc2', null from #test
where desc2 is null

insert into #test2
select id, null, null, 'desc3' from #test
where desc3 is null


update #test2
set desc1 = isnull(desc2, desc3),
desc2 = null
where desc1 is null

update #test2
set desc2 = isnull(desc3, null),
desc3 = null
where desc2 is null

select * from #test2

drop table #test
drop table #test2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Does it matter that I have read-only access to this database?  Will that prevent me from creating a temp table?

Comment: Yep, I assume so, but can you create in another database that has access to that one?

Comment: Not on this server.  My company has a very strict security policy.  I appreciate the suggestion though, and will keep it in mind when if I can ever create databases here.  Thanks!!